# Qual é o modelo ideal para criação de classes que envolvam o banco de dados?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mvc

Tenho uma dúvida muito forte sobre qual é a melhor maneira de se criar classes para "interagir" com o banco de dados (em PHP, no caso). Por exemplo:

Eu preciso que validações muito específicas de cada tabela sejam executadas antes de registrar algo no banco.

Sendo assim, é o ideal criar classes como: `Insert, Update e Delete`? Ou todas estas na verdade devem ser métodos de uma classe Database? Ou ainda seria melhor criar cada método deste para cada model(MVC) do meu projeto?

Enfim, qual seria o melhor modo de fazer isto?

Obrigado!

Comment: Aí vai muito da opinião de cada um. Eu, por exemplo, acho que para usar DB em PHP o ideal é não criar classe nenhuma e usar o que já tem pronto. Outros podem pensar diferente.

Comment: Sobre a `Database`, acho que `ORM` pode trazer alguma luz. Geralmente cada modelo tem seus próprios métodos que podem ou não usar o BD - há operações no modelo que podem gerar log de texto.